# calling jni method from other jni library

Tags: android, java-native-interface, jnienv

Is it possible to call jni method of 1 library from another method of different jni library ?
for eg: I have 2 libraries lib_1.so and lib_2.so.

I want to call a method get_interface() of lib_1.so from lib_2.so.

Is this possible?
If yes, please share the example of how this can be done.

Answer (score 2):

When calling from one shared library to another, its really no longer jni, its just native code(c->c or c++ -> c++).  Include the .h and invoke the function as you would normally, passing whatever parameters the function requires.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do `dlopen("lib2.so")` from `lib1.so` so you have a handle to your `lib2.so` library and then using that handle you can call the methods.